# Media Query not working on Android 4.2.2 Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, media-queries, android-browser

I have a mobile site with media queries inside the main CSS file. The site display correct as per the media queries on iphones, tabs, and android Chrome. But when it comes to the android browser it doesn't  always display right. I am testing on a Galaxy Nexus with 4.2.2 and my media query doesn't seem to tigger. But on a Galaxy S 3 it does work. Anyone have a clue? I've used the viewport meta tag as well.

```
@media all 
and (min-width : 351px)
and (max-width : 459px)
```